# How do I call a member function pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, syntax, pointer-to-member

I am using C++11 with GNU tool chain on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32 bit. I know similar questions have been asked, but I haven't found exactly this one, and I wasn't able to get anything that worked from what is already posted, so here goes:

I have code like this:

```
enum class FUNC_TYPES { FUNCTYPE_1,FUNCTYPE_2,FUNCTYPE_3};

class AClass
{
...

typedef void (AClass::* TFunc )( );
std::map<FUNC_TYPES, TFunc> mFuncMap;


void doStuff();

....

}
```

I initialize  mFuncMap like this:

```
void AClass::initFuncMap( )
{
    mFuncMap[FUNC_TYPES::FUNCTYPE_1] = & AClass::doStuff;
}
```

All that compiles fine.

Now I want to call the mapped function pointer.

I tried this form, which I know works for function pointers that are not for member functions.

```
mFuncMap[FUNC_TYPES::FUNCTYPE_1]( );
```

This generates a very long explanatory compiler error:

> error: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function in
>   (AClass*)this)->AClass::mFuncMap.std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare,
>   _Alloc>...

I tried just about every form of de-referencing I can think of and that I found from searching around - with parenthesis, without them, etc. etc. etc... but I cannot get the syntax right to make this call.

What is the correct syntax for calling the mapped member function? Is there something wrong with my declaration or initialization that is causing this problem?

Comment: @user3477950: He probably expected `this` to be used, just as it would be if you wrote `doStuff()` instead of `this->doStuff()`. It's not a leap if you don't already know.

Comment: Next time please narrow down your problem further. This has nothing to do with maps so maps should not be part of the question. If you'd properly narrowed down the problem, you'd have eventually realised that it comes down to "how do I invoke a pointer-to-member-function?" and then you can simply Google it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - _He probably expected this to be used.._ thank you. My though was exactly that: for a non-member function pointer `()` works without any further qualification, as I explained in the question. I assumed that the implicit this-> would work as well. Nothing I found explained otherwise, and I did look around quite a bit.( I edited the title and the tags)

Comment: @Vector: when getting a complex error message, I advise that you break down your statement in multiple pieces to isolate the issue. `TFunc const func = mFuncMap[FUNC_TYPES::FUNCTYPE_1]; func();` points out the issue is with `func`, not `mFuncMap`, and thus gets you closer to the answer (and reduces the clutter in your question).

Comment: @MatthieuM - thanks for the advice. Many of those error messages a very long and arcane, etc. Very difficult to parse them and understand them for me - I am not an expert in this language - it is a sideline for me, not my 'bread and butter".

Comment: @Vector: Yes, having peeked at the insides of a compiler I can assure you that the people writing them really care about having good diagnosis but it really is hard, and often lead to sub-optimal diagnostics. By having short statements, you facilitate their job, and as a result, you get more accurate diagnostics (often) or at the very least a smaller piece of code to investigate :D

Comment: @MatthieuM - I'm not faulting anybody. From my own work I know how hard that sort of thing can be. Just a bit discouraging that people tend to downvote something because the OP isn't a world class expert. Let's face it, there are all different levels of expertise, and if you were expert in everything, you would have no questions at all! It's all relative.

Comment: @Vector: On SO votes on questions are more concerned about the *form*, than the *content*; we are all here to learn after all. Of course, that's a broad guideline and everyone tends to do as he wishes, in your case even though the final score might be chaffing you are better off having asked score-wise (`3*-2 + 2*+5 = +4`).

Comment: @MatthieuM.- I don't need to get better off in terms of score if I'm asking a question that I just want answered to improve my own knowledge. If I do get some points, that's a bonus, as long as I get an answer to the question. But the downvotes do hurt - I am often reluctant to ask questions because someone will downvote - particularly with C++ that is the case because there is already so much knowledge and expertise out there in that language that someone will invariably come along and say "this is so simple and you're just not trying"...

Comment: Downvotes are not anything to do with your level of expertise; they are for questions that will never help anyone else because they are "debug my code plz" questions. SO is not a forum or help site!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I don't think I'm guilty of asking any "debug my code plz" questions. I do know how to debug. I ask questions when I come across a problem that I can't figure out and I'm pretty sure is not because of a bug but because I'm lacking a certain bit of knowledge. Perhaps you call that "a help site"? "One man's 'help' is another man's 'tough problem'. See [**Preventing serial down voting...**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260098/preventing-serial-down-voting-when-almost-every-question-seems-to-show-no-resear/260243#260243) and comments there.

Comment: @Vector: Didn't say you were guilty! I wouldn't have answered your question if you were. That said, whilst we're talking about this, in the future you should consider posting a more complete [testcase](http://sscce.org); I didn't downvote you but you _didn't_ fully debug your problem (you failed to identify that the map had nothing to do with it, and thus more than half the question and its code are  a red herring!) and that may be why someone did.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - _you didn't fully debug your problem (you failed to identify that the map had nothing to do with it)_ - you missed the last line in my question... If I would have been able to fully **identity the problem** indeed my question would indeed have been set up differently... Again: The concept of **Relavity** should be quite familiar someone who is building _A space sim utilising four dimensions..._ :)

Comment: Not sure why you keep saying "relativity", but you're misusing the term.

Comment: I don't think I'm misusing the term: A simple way of understanding  relativity is that someone who is moving @ c-1 has a different ('dilated') scale of measurement than someone who is moving @ c-1000, when both are viewed by someone moving at c-10000. You are moving @ c-1. I am moving @ c-1000...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with maps, and nothing to do with typedefs. [You have a pointer-to-member-function and you're not invoking it properly](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/macro-for-ptr-to-memfn.html).

You need an `AClass` to run the function on:

```
AClass& a = someAClassSomewhere();
(a.*(mFuncMap[FUNC_TYPES::FUNCTYPE_1]))();
```

Of course this is really ugly, so consider binding the object ahead of time:

```
typedef std::function<void()> TFunc;
std::map<FUNC_TYPES, TFunc> mFuncMap;

// ...

mFuncMap[FUNC_TYPES::FUNCTYPE_1] = std::bind(&AClass::doStuff, this);

// ...

mFuncMap[FUNC_TYPES::FUNCTYPE_1]();
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71fa1b27be796771))

Comment: @Vector: Sure it does, [and here's a live example to prove it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71fa1b27be796771). You're quoting from the definition of `result_type`, but that is not the return type of `std::bind`. From the same reference page that you cite: "A function object of unspecified type `T`, for which `std::is_bind_expression<T>::value == true`, **and which can be stored in `std::function`**."

Comment: OK - I see - I just ran your sample. Can't argue with the code. I see I misquoted the doc there -  `result_type` is not `return value`.  Must be something else I'm screwing up. C++ is a "hobby" for me - doesn't pay my bills - I do it at very late at night...

Comment: @Vector: Mine pays the bills _and_ I do it very late at night ;)

Comment: My day job is with Delphi and/or C# - been doing it so long I can (and do...) do it in my sleep - during the day... I save my nights for _fun_ . I am from the Dbase/Clipper world-after hours I have messed with many languages, particularly Python, Go and C++.  C++ is the one I keep coming back to - most of the other stuff besides Object Pascal is just poorly implemented C++ workarounds/subsets as far as I can tell.  C++ beats everything else out there, but it's big and complex-unfortunately I don't have enough time to master it well enough to pay the bills, but I enjoy learning and exploring.

Comment: `std::function` is so good. Replaces the need for compiler closure extensions.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  OK - I got `std::bind()` right now. **Big** improvement.