# c++ calling function when using map of function pointer

Tags: c++, dictionary, pointer-to-member

I set up this account mainly because I couldn't find answers elsewhere. I checked, various tutorials or questions/ answers on stackoverflow and different pages.

I'm programming a terminal based textadventure and need a map of functions. This is what I got (I left out all the stuff that isn't of interesting for the problem)

```
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class CPlayer
{
private:

    //Players functions:
    typedef void(CPlayer::*m_PlayerFunction)(void); //Function-pointer points to various player 
                                                    //functions
    map<char*, m_PlayerFunction> *m_FunctionMap;    //Map containing all player functions

public:
    //Constructor
    CPlayer(char* chName, CRoom* curRoom, CInventory* Inventory);


    //Functions:
    bool useFunction(char* chPlayerCommand);
    void showDoors(); //Function displaing all doors in the room
    void showPeople(); //Function displaying all people in the room


};

#endif
```

```
#include "CPlayer.h"
#include <iostream>


CPlayer::CPlayer(char chName[128], CRoom* curRoom, CInventory *Inventory)
{
    //Players functions
    m_FunctionMap = new map<char*, CPlayer::m_PlayerFunction>;
    m_FunctionMap->insert(std::make_pair((char*)"show doors", &CPlayer::showDoors));
    m_FunctionMap->insert(std::make_pair((char*)"show people", &CPlayer::showPeople));
}






//Functions

//useFunction, calls fitting function, return "false", when no function ist found
bool CPlayer::useFunction(char* chPlayerCommand)
{
    CFunctions F;
    map<char*, m_PlayerFunction>::iterator it = m_FunctionMap->begin();

    for(it; it!=m_FunctionMap->end(); it++)
    {
        if(F.compare(chPlayerCommand, it->first) == true)
        {
            cout << "Hallo" << endl;
            (it->*second)();
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Now, the problem is the following:

If I call the function this way:
`(it->*second)();`
which seems to be how it is supposed to be done, I get the following error:
`error: ‘second’ was not declared in this scope`

If I call the function this way:
 `(*it->second)();`
which is what I got from this thread: [Using a STL map of function pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136998/using-a-stl-map-of-function-pointers), I get following error: 
`error: invalid use of unary ‘ * ’ on pointer to member`

I'd be very glad if someone could help me. Thanks ahead for all the upcoming answers.

PS: It would also be interesting to know whether "map" or "unordered_map" is the better way of solving this problem.

As I said, thanks ahead:
GB

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I call a member function pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24325612/how-do-i-call-a-member-function-pointer)

Comment: Did the proposed duplicate question or searching for "calling pointer to member function" help you solve the problem?

Comment: There is issue with using `const char *` as key in a map. And there is no reason to make it worse casting it to `char *`

Comment: Using pointers as map keys is very unlikely to work well. And iterating over a map looking for a key is not the way to use a map.

Comment: I don't think that's an exact duplicate of the above question. There are two operators `->*` and `.*`, and these two questions cover each one of them.

Comment: what about std::function? Also, why using new?

Comment: You need a `std::unordered_map<std::string, m_PlayerFunction>`, and hold it by value!  That way you can just do `auto it = m_FunctionMap.find(chPlayerCommand);  if (it != m_FunctionMap.end()) (this->*(it->second))();`

Comment: Reason I'm using char*, is that the player Command might also contain people, items, door or room names, which are also char*, as they might change during the game, thus char* not const char.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difficulty may be that it is at the same time a map, and it involves pointer-to-members, which makes the syntax to invoke more complicated with lots of parentheses that must be at the right positions. I think it should be something like this:

```
(this->*(it->second))()
```

Alternatively, as Rakete1111 points out, the following works as well:

```
(this->*it->second)()
```

(Note that the latter is less verbose, but also less easy to read for people who do not have the operator precedence on the top of their minds).

Comment: Yes, but you don't need the nested ones: `(this->*it->second)()` is ok too.

Comment: That's a good point. `->` is documented to have a higher precedence than `->*` indeed. I added it, but still personally prefer the extra parentheses for readability.

Comment: Actually, I would split it:  `const auto fp = it->second; (this->*fp)();`, pointers-to-member-functions are so insanely complicated, that it is worth spelling it out.